# GDAL installation error on PyCharm IDE in Windows 64 bit environment

Tags: python, windows, gis, pycharm, gdal

I am trying to install the GDAL Package on PyCharm IDE. The command executed is pip install GDAL but I am getting an error stating:

**AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2**

Can you please suggest how to rectify this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this installations msi files

1st > http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1800-x64-gdal-1-11-1-mapserver-6-4-1/GDAL-1.11.1.win-amd64-py2.7.msi

2nd > http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1800-x64-gdal-1-11-1-mapserver-6-4-1/GDAL-1.11.1.win-amd64-py2.7.msi

From 
http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php

Comment: For installing on my mac, I am using anaconda and I used the following command  conda install gdal